# Apache2 and Its Directories

Tags: apache2, directory

Assume my webserver hosts multiple domains. Where is my directory that contains the active web domains?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This probably should be on a different Stack Exchange site to ask questions of this nature (see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)). However, it would be on-topic at [the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: Questions about how to use Ubuntu programs are generally on-topic for Ask Ubuntu, and this is no different.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/` hold all available sites with 1 file per site. The domains are inside the files.

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` holds the sites that are active. Again: the domains are inside the files. These files can be symlinks to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost xx.yyy.com:80>
    ServerAlias xx.yyy2.com
    ServerAlias xxxxx
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    DocumentRoot /dir/dir/dir/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On
 </VirtualHost>
```

Try to keep files outside of `/var/www/`. `/var` is often not a separate partition and is also used for storing printer files and mysql files so if any of these 3 make it fill up your system using the machine to fix this problem might be more difficult than needed.

It also makes it easier when you need upgrade or re-install your system, add more space to your system or need to use several different operating systems.